# Markdown in careers.stackoverflow.com cover letters

Tags: feature-request, jobs, markdown

One of the things I love about the Stack Exchange sites is how pervasive Markdown is. You can literally use it almost everywhere. Heck, I'm using it right now, as I type this.

So, you can imagine my surprise when I submitted a cover letter recently on [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) and discovered that cover letters are one of the few places that Markdown isn't supported.

Is there a reason for this, or is it just an oversight? I would love to be able to use Markdown in cover letters when applying for jobs on [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Lies; no Markdown was used while you were typing that sentence.

Comment: Lies; Plain text is a proper subset of Markdown :P

Comment: If that's the case then what are you complaining about? Careers cover letters fully support the aforementioned subset. :)